# Ruby script, best method to store login information for an API?

Tags: ruby, api

I'm currently working on a script (command line tool) for work to help me manage expose consoles.

At first I was passing three arguments to the script each time I used it to login into the consoles, for example:

```
$ nexose-magic.rb -u user -p password -i 192.168.1.2 --display-scans
```

It's not very efficient, so I created a config.yml file that stores console information in a hash.

```
$ nexpose-magic.rb -c console --display-scans
```

I believe the tool will be useful to admins out there, so I'd like to share it in a gem. I can't figure out how to get my config.yml file to work with a gem install..It can't find the config.yml file! It's easy to point it at the relative path in my development directory, but once I create a gem that relative path isn't so relative anymore. How do I point nexpose-magic.rb at the config.yml file?

Is there a better way to handle something like this?

Comment: The place that springs to mind is in a dotfile in the user's home directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a gem that include a `configure` class. This class has a `load` method that will take a directory as an argument. Then, you can pass the directory where you are currently working.

A nice way of preparing your gem is to create a `Configuration` singleton class in your gem:

```
require 'singleton'
class Configuration
  include Singleton

  attr_accessor :config, :app_path
  def load(app_path)
    @app_path = app_path

    #load the config file and store the data
    @config = YAML.load_file( File.join(@app_path,'config','config.yml')) 
  end  

end
```

In your main class :

```
module MyFancyGem

  class << self
    #define a class method that configure the gem
    def configure(app_path)
      # Call load method with given path
      config.load(app_path)
    end

    # MyFancyGem.config will refer to the singleton Configuration class
    def config
      MyFancyGem::Configuration.instance
    end

  end

end
```

Usage:

```
-Working directory
  - my_new_script
  - Gemfile
  - config/
    - config.yml
```

In my_new_script :

```
require 'bundler'
Bundler.setup(:default)
require 'my_fancy_gem'
MyFancyGem.configure(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__),"./")) #here, you define the path

MyFancyGem.hello_world
```

I hope that's clear enough. I was actually about to write a blog post to explain this particular point (I hope in a more complete version of it). Let me know if you're interested !

Comment: So if I'm running a executable that is present in ruby's bin dir, I would be passing the config file argument every time I run the command?